# Apache configuration in WebSphere

Tags: apache, websphere

My original question is now edited to avoid confusion:

I have configured a web server(Apache) and an application server profile on the same machine.

1) Generated plug-in, propagated it and verified the plugin-cfg.xml
2)Installed DefaultApplication.ear(snoop) to test the connectivity
3)Checked virtual hosts for application servers and installed app
4)made sure port numbers are not duplicated
5)Restarted application server and apache

When I try to hit the URL to test snoop, no luck.

```
http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:9080/snoop --> This is now WORKING, bit not port 80

http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/snoop
Not Found
The requested URL /snoop was not found on this server
Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at xx.xx.xx.xxx Port 80
```

Can you please let me know what is missing ?

Note: I have found that there is no /bin directory under /opt/IBM/WebSphere/plugIns
Only Conf and Logs directory are availabale. WAS version is 8.5.5.7

Comment: Is that the output of several different HTTP requests AND netstat?    Start with basics.  What complete URL did you test and what response did you get?

Comment: That is a netstat output to show the ports 80 and 9080 are Listening. I tried http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/snoop and http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:9080/snoop. no luck and the outputs are in my questions above, Thanks Covener

Comment: Well, you got an HTTP response, so the ports are definitely listening. Why are there multiple HTTP responses listed and what do they represent?

Comment: That is just a list of netstat -tupln to show the actively listening ports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix the problems.

**Problem #1: to get the snoop launching as  xx.xx.xx.xxx:9080/snoop**
1) In WebSpher Console, Server Types -> WebSphere application servers -> Server1 -> Installed Applications -> DefaultApplication.ear -> Modules -> Manage Modules -> Default Web Application -> Should be mapped to both the App Server and Web Server

2) Regenerate plug-in, propagate, restart Apache and App Server(better off) and then  xx.xx.xx.xxx:9080/snoop started to show up

**Problem #2: to get the snoop launching as  xx.xx.xx.xxx/snoop**
1) In the default WAS install from our VM provisioning, Plug-in was not installed properly. Hence I installed the WebServer plugin as
`aal-imcl install com.ibm.websphere.PLG.v85_8.5.5006.20150529_0536 -acceptLicense -installationDirectory /opt/IBM/Plugins` (Please note I created a new directory for Plug-in instead of /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins
2) Added the below lines to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule was_ap22_module "/opt/IBM/Plugins/bin/64bits/mod_was_ap22_http.so"
   WebSpherePluginConfig /opt/IBM/WebSphere/Plugins/config/SAF2TEST/plugin-cfg.xml
```

3) Regenerate plug-in, propagate, restart Apache and App Server(better off) and then  xx.xx.xx.xxx/snoop started to show up

Happy to share my experience to WAS newbees like myself.

Answer (score 5):

You need to map the DefaultApplication to both your applicaton server (or cluster) as well as the HTTP server, taking note of its context root for the included web module, before generating and propagating the plugin-cfg.xml.

If you can't get a response from WAS on port 9080, there's generally no sense in seeing what happens when you add an Apache server in-between.

Comment: Default application is mapped to default virtual host(port 80 and 9080). Context root for web modules reads as URI(DefaultWebApplication.war,WEB-INF/web.xml) and ContextRoot(/snoop)

Applicaiton server is also mapped to default virtual host

Comment: Found some luck. mapped both App Serber and Web Server to the application in Manage Module section and regenerated propagaed plug-Ins. Now snoop works on port 9080 http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:9080/snoop. but NOT on port 80? http://xx.xx.xx.xxx/snoop

Comment: @suj: Update your question with your progress so that new answers can come in, or existing answers can be revised. Be sure to include the new errors/stack trace as applicable.